# How to pass value in log4j2 JSON layout configuration the value of KeyValuePair from code?

Tags: log4j2, java.util.logging

I want to pass some value from my code to my logs which in JSON format. The key of that value should define in log configuration file.

My XML configuration log4j2-spring.xml is as follow:

```
  <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <JsonLayout complete="false" stacktraceAsString="true" eventEOL="true" compact="true">
            <KeyValuePair key="ValueFromCode" value="Value"/>                
        </JsonLayout>
   </Console>
```

When I write
`Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());`
`logger.info("TestXXX")`

the above configuration writes log as

{"instant":{"epochSecond":1625138085,"nanoOfSecond":35827700},"thread":"XXXXX","level":"INFO","loggerName":"XXXXXXX","message":"TestXXX","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","threadId":XX,"threadPriority":X,"**ValueFromCode**":"Value"}

I want to pass the value of this Key **ValueFromCode** from my code. Something like,

`Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(this.getClass());`
`logger.info("TestXXX","some value for Key ValueFromCode")`

and this should write my log as
{"instant":{"epochSecond":1625138085,"nanoOfSecond":35827700},"thread":"XXXXX","level":"INFO","loggerName":"XXXXXXXXXX","message":"TestXXX","endOfBatch":false,"loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLogger","threadId":XX,"threadPriority":X,"**ValueFromCode**":"**some value for Key ValueFromCode**"}

Please tell me if this is achievable. If there is any alternate way to achieve the same.